# relative and absolute positioning in CSS and formatting

Tags: css

I have the below HTML in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v6E9a/  .The issue is that the footer is overlapping with the body.If I change the body position to relative then it all lines up correctly but I need to have absolute there to support some other functionality.

I m really not that good with CSS.Can someone please have a look at the html and tell me how i can line the head body and footer correctly.

```
<div id="s4-workspace" style="width: 1920px; height: 748px; overflow:scroll">
    <div id="s4-bodyContainer" style="position:relative">   

        <div class="headerSection" style="position:relative ;border : 3px solid red">           
            <div class="globalHeader">  
                header
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div>          
            <div id="contentRow" style="position:relative">
                <div class="fixedWidthMain" style="position:relative">   
                         <div class="fixedWidthMain" style="position:absolute ;border:3px solid blue">   
                         main data
                </div>           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--PAGE FOOTER SECTION-->
    <div class="pageFooterSection" style="clear: both;position:relative ;border:3px solid green">      
  footer
    </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Start over? All these inline styles are no bueno.
http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5ftWf/

"to support some other functionality" is basically the most important thing - and you skipped it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I cannot use that style HTML since this HTML is generated by a product.Sorry for the inline styles I just added it to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute take up no space, and that's why the footer is on top. There are many ways to work around this. if your main fx, have a fixed height, you can add that value as a margin-top to your footer.

fixed-main height fx 400px

pageFooterSection gets a margin-top of 400px